# What constitutes a programming language and how does one copyright a programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, licensing, legal

I've decided to create a programming language of my own, mostly just for fun. However, I got interested in the legal aspect of it all.

You can, for example, licence specific programs under specific terms. However, how do you go about licensing a *language*? Also, by that I don't just mean the implementation of the language (compiler & VM), but the standard itself. Is there something else to a programming language I'm missing?

What I would like to achieve by such licensing:

1. Make it completely FOSS (can a language even be FOSS, or is that the implementation that can be FOSS?)
2. Establish myself as the author (can you legally be an author of a language? Or, again, just the implementation?)
3. Make it so that anyone implementing my language would be required to attribute me (MIT-style. Please note that I do not have any hopes for anyone actually ever doing that though, I'm just learning.)

I think that the solution would be to separately license the VM and the compiler for my language, as "the official implementation", and then license the design document *as the language itself*.

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Re (1): A language spec isn't software, so FOSS doesn't apply. Also, if I came across a language whose author attempted such a thing, for whatever purpose, I'd be *extremely* cautious (that is to say, I'd probably not use it at all). It reeks of control addiction, mistrust, and poor knowledge of legal issues.

Comment: I'm a little at a loss as to what your end-goal is here. Maybe if we knew that, we could help you fill in the gaps as to how to achieve it. Also would be useful to know who your target market is.

Comment: Wait, how does labeling anything reek of control addiction, @delnan? Or were you referring to copyrighting a spec? AFAIK, copyrighting isn't inherently evil, it doesn't have to be restrictive at all.

Comment: @Yannbane - Rather by definition, copyright is more restrictive than public domain. Even if the only right you retain is that your name is associated to it, though that leads to delnan's concerns.

Comment: I guess I will keep the spec in the public domain then.

Comment: You could have the language spec document with a free licence e.g. CC-BY-SA....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, isn't that essentially copyrighting it? When I said "copyright", I meant licensing under the MIT/X11 license, which is based on the "do what you want but attribute the creator" principle.

Comment: Also, that license seems to be very restrictive, just like GPL.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but copyrighting a document (even if it specifies a language) is not copyrighting a language. For instance, I do use copyrighted dictionnaries, and I do speak French without violating them.

Comment: @Yannbane Yes, CC-BY-SA is quite restrictive (it's copyleft), certainly more restrictive than MIT/X11. And yes, you need to have copyright to apply any of the popular FOSS licenses or the CC licenses. But since you can't grant anyone any rights without first having copyright on the thing in question, that's rarely what we mean by copyright. One more note: CC-0 is recommended over "just public domain" by CC and FSF, though I don't know how many of the reasons also apply to non-software (it does seem more resilient to idiotic jurisdictions).

Comment: @Yannbane: you say "that license seems...". Which license are you talking about? At least a couple license have been mentioned in the comments to this question. At the moment, you comment is immediately below one talking about the MIT/X11 license, which isn't at all like the GPL. Is that the one you were referring to?

Comment: Wouldn't the implementation be something that is patented rather than copyrighted?

Comment: @BryanOakley, sorry, I was talking about the that CC license mentioned above.

Comment: @Jetti I don't think so (though with today's patent systems, it's probably just a matter of how inventive the lawyers are). Individual innovations, which are *used* in the implementation (e.g. a new way to implement virtual method dispatch) *might* be patent-worthy. But the whole implementation ought to consist mostly of long-known concepts.

Comment: @delnan, if the language spec is *formal* (i.e., presented in form of, say, denotational semantics), one can argue it is a software.

Comment: I've read recently that APIs can't be copyrighted, though I've lost the reference and don't know if that's universal. With IANAL disclaimers, I would have thought a programming language is a special case of an API - the API that's provided by particular compilers/interpreters - and is probably no more/less copyrightable than an API.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Disclaimer.IANAL();

You can't copyright a programming language no more than you can copyright a spoken language. You can license a particular implementation of the language and even sell that compiler much how Borland did with Delphi for many years.

Many languages today have a BDFL (Benevolent Dictator for Life) who determines what goes into the language and what doesn't. Python, Ruby, and Perl are all examples of that.

Other languages have officially designed standards by one of several standards boards, typically ANSI, ECMA, or ISO. Examples include C, C++, and Javascript.

Some languages fall into murkier areas due to politicking between companies. Java is an example because Microsoft sits on some of the standards boards.

Some languages move from one to another, typically from BDFL to Standardized, C is a good example.

Depending on the specification of the language, some compiler writers may implement different features in different ways (CPython vs PyPy for example) or add features (Microsoft C++ vs GNU C++ or MySQL vs PostGreSQL vs SQL Server)

Comment: [Loglan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loglan) is a precedent for the non-copyrightable status of constructed languages. [Lojban](http://www.lojban.org/tiki/Lojban) is effectively an open reimplementation of Loglan. On the other hand, Sun sued Microsoft for their [Visual J++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_J%2B%2B) implementation of Java…

Comment: @JonPurdy: With Java, it's a trademark issue, not a copyright issue. Look at how LiveScript became Javascript, while it was in Sun/Netscape's combined interests, later Microsoft released JScript to show similarity while avoiding trademark issues, and then later everyone agreed to ECMAScript as a common name.

Comment: Hi @JonPurdy, could you tell me over what can you actually get sued by Oracle or some other corporation? I'm wondering because the name of my language is very similar to Java - it's "Kava", which actually means "coffee" in my native language, just like Java. I don't believe anyone at Oracle will ever notice Kava, I'm asking just for the sake of knowing. Also I follow you on YouTube, nice to see you active on my questions, and why haven't you posted any videos in a long time?

Comment: @JonPurdy,@pdr I think there were also issues of contract law in the dispute between Sun and Microsoft. Microsoft had licensed JVM technology from Sun and part of the license was agreeing not to produce non-standard implementations of Java.

Comment: @Yannbane, there is a huge body of law in the US and Europe over what are called registered trademarks. A firm registers a claim to a word, phrase, or logo as representative of their business. For example, Starbucks trademarked the term "Starbucks" for coffee shops decades ago. A person named Starbucks cannot now start a coffee shop named Starbucks because the Starbucks company got there first. The trademark doesn't affect the use of their name in other contexts. See Apple Music vs Apple Computer for a famous and complex trade mark case.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant: As I understand it, there's no "JVM Technology" to license. MS had licensed the trademark so they could write their own JVM. Sun were quite happy to do this but, as well as payment, they require a certain level of adherence to standard, which MS (as was their wont in those days) didn't even come close to reaching. Something like that anyway. As you say, it's complex. :)

Comment: @pdr As far as I can remember there was a very precise specification a what a Java implementation should provide (including a few thousand tests that an implementation should pass). Microsoft was sued because they had a non-standard implementation (probably to lock-in users by distributing applets that would only work with Internet Explorer). After the strategy of distributing a non-standard implementation of Java failed, Microsoft went on to create C#.

Comment: @Giorgio - precisely. What Sun was objecting to was MSFT calling their language Java while making significant changes (to lock it to MSFT's platform) essentially they were producing a counterfeit Java

Comment: @Yannbane: You could be targeted for a lawsuit only if you directly infringe upon their intellectual property. For example, if you made a competing programming language, also called Java, then Oracle could target you for misuse of their registered trademark. But you wouldn’t want to do that anyway. As for my videos…it’s a long story. Maybe I should make a video about it.

Comment: @JonPurdy, thanks for clearing that up. Well, you certainly should make a new video. :)

Comment: Maybe you can't copyright a language, but that doesn't stop people from trying... From [Loxian, a language created by Enya](http://self.gutenberg.org/articles/loxian): `Enya and Ryan consider Loxian to be under copyright; reproducing the language without the permission of Ryan or Enya's record label, Aigle Records, is considered a copyright violation. As with Klingon, it is disputed whether a language itself can be copyrighted.`

Answer (score 9):

Any attempt to restrict / control / own a language is doomed to failure. In order for a language to become widely used, people must feel a) that it solves a problem *better* than some existing, established language, and b)  they are comfortable that they won't suddenly be on the wrong end of a license / law suit. If they think that that is even possible, they will go elsewhere.

I offer the absolute Tragedy of Java, as performed by Larry Ellison (AKA Oracle) and Google. Ellison performed a global-scale legal [faceplant](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1VAO3o3B50) that accomplished 2 things:

1. He showed the world that he would sue anyone he thought he could get money from, and
2. He guaranteed that future developments that were not *absolutely* already tied to Java would choose *anything* other than Java.

Google didn't just win this lawsuit, they [eviscerated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disembowelment) Oracle's pathetic claims of patent and copyright. After this, no one I know will place any faith *whatsoever* in any "open source technology" that has Oracle's fingerprints on it (think: MySQL).

If you want, you can skip the developer-centuries behind Java and go straight to being ignored ... just have all developer's sign a contract before they can use your new language.

Comment: +1 for making it perfectly clear. You hit the nail with your 2nd point about Java. This has been a major factor in deciding whether to keep on using Java or create a similar language myself. Though, I don't really expect people to use it, as I have said, it's for personal and educational purposes. But, I'd like to keep my options open.

Comment: Update: in May 2014 a federal circuit court reversed that decision and said that APIs could be copyrighted. https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2014/05/dangerous-ruling-oracle-v-google-federal-circuit-reverses-sensible-lower-court

Comment: But that wasn't the real point of my post. After the total debacle of Oracle's power-play with Java, no one in their right mind, and with any knowledge of history, will knowingly place this kind of noose around their company's or project's neck. If anything, the reversal by the Appellate Court only serves to give even greater weight to the argument for using only OSS tools and languages. It's amazing, and deeply ironic, that an a**hole like Larry Ellison should be the person to drive home the true value of Libre/Free software to even the most hard-headed capitalist or business person.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a grammar for your language and assert your copyright over that. Of course, that wouldn't protect you against someone writing a different grammar that described the same language.

My biggest question would be "why would you want to". After all, you probably want people to adopt your language. If someone else claimed to have created it, then simply having a good web presence would be enough to enable you to call them a liar.

As others have noted, if your main goal is to prevent others from stealing the `name` of your language, a trademark would be more useful.

Comment: Writing a grammar for the language would still not protect it. The only thing it would do, is stop someone else re-writing the grammar in a similar way to you. I could write a grammar for the English language, that wouldn't then stop you from being able to post on SE though.

Comment: Gavin - I wrote.... "that wouldn't protect you against someone writing a different grammar that described the same language." I hope this makes clear that such a copyright would not protect the language, only that way of describing the language. Still - it might make a person feel better.

Answer (score 1):

There have been different answers to this question over time:

In 2012, a similar question was [answered](http://www.groklaw.net/articlebasic.php?story=20120531173633275) "you cannot" in the Oracle v.s. Google case over the use of the Java API in Android, and [a similar answer](http://www.groklaw.net/articlebasic.php?story=20120502083035371) was given in the case of WPL's implementation of the SAS programming language in their own product. The rationale for this answer was that interopability between different implementations of a language requires copying of the syntax of a programming language, and thus doing so should be allowed under "fair use" rules.

In 2014, however, the US court of appeals [decided](http://cafc.uscourts.gov/images/stories/opinions-orders/13-1021.Opinion.5-7-2014.1.PDF) that the just legal answer was indeed "yes, you can", on the grounds that to provide interopability (or not), and under what rules is at the sole discretion of the original copyright holder. In this most recent interpretation, if someone does not want you to be compatible with their programming language, API or other interface specification, they have every right to stop you.

**In a nutshell, as of 2014 it is probably fair to assume: yes, a programming language (its syntax, structure and sequence of language constructs) can be copyrighted**

Note that copyright law is subject to local interpretaton and that rules in your country may differ. If in doubt consult a lawyer...

(removed the rest of the argument, see history)

Disclaimer: IANAL

Comment: Annnddd...this ruling was just overturned.  Oracle appelaed, and this time the judges weren't programmers.

Comment: @jmoreno thanks for pointing this out. updated the answer to reflect this new development...

Comment: Just want to say, not a lawyer or a psychiatrist, just a programmer, but the 2014 ruling seems borderline insane to me.  It's a bunch of commands!

Comment: Please don't add to the confusion. OP asked about copyrightability of a programming language. Oracle vs Google was about APIs and had nothing to do with the Java programming language itself.